# React Native build failed with unable to find valid certification path to requested target error

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I am trying to build my react native app, but getting below error. I have tried by switching internet connections and I have imported certificates into my java but nothing works.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:+.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build:gradle.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> > Failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build:gradle.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> > Failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build:gradle.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:+.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Failed to list versions for com.google.gms:google-services.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> > Failed to list versions for com.google.gms:google-services.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> > Failed to list versions for com.google.gms:google-services.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 45s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

My build.gradle file -

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 19
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 27

        googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.1" // added for FCM
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com"}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:+")
        classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:+') // added for FCM
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com/" }  // added for FCM
    }
}
```